Data cloud licenses not visible in sandbox
Recently SF has announced that Data cloud becomes available in Sandbox environments, however, we don't see Data cloud licenses or permission sets available in Sandbox.
Why? what is the workaround or how we can fix it?

We are going to suggest to the client to click "match production licences" button on sandbox. Hopefully that should bring the data cloud licenses in sandbox.
Otherwise we would have to open SF Support case.
Also, we need to apply for beta
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_data_cloud_sandbox_create.htm&type=5
In your production org, select Data Cloud Setup.
In the Quick Find box, enter Feature Manager, and then select Feature Manager.
In the Data Cloud In Sandbox panel, click Enable.
Looks like it is not enough to click 'Match Production Licenses' but we also actually need to create or refresh a sandbox

If it's a demo org then sandbox licenses need to be added. When it was available in Beta you didn't need licenses but now that it's GA you do.

when, it is not a demo org. but a real client production org. still doesn't work. going to discuss with client account executives

Yeah if it's a production org then I'd expect those licenses to be there. Opening a case is a good idea.

well, we are going to have a call with client account executive today. I am confused since we configured 'Data Cloud in Sandbox (Beta)' in production and it still is called like that in Production. However, in sandbox it doesn't work. We need to know if there is anything client need to buy or there is some technical issue.

Yes, SKUs need to be added, the credits that are consumed through this process are charged separately and at a different rate, and need to be added to your account.

Data Cloud has recently gone GA (Nov '24). If you'd like Data Cloud Sandbox features enabled in your account, currently these are the requirements:

Consumption-based version of Data Cloud (Not available for CDP as of Nov '24)
Core Sandbox - this can be Full, Partial, Dev Pro, or Dev sandbox versions
Data Cloud Sandbox must be provisioned for your account along with consumption credits for Data Services, Storage, Real time (if needed), and Segments / Activations (If needed)

Data Cloud Sandbox does charge for consumption which requires the purchase of credits, or transfer of production credits to sandbox. Contact your Account Executive for the full details.
Once you have the licenses enabled in your account, you can follow the directions on this page: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_data_cloud_sandbox_create.htm&type=5

yesterday we had a call with Nate and Aaron and we have asked what is Real time SKU but they weren't able to answer. While client didn't expect any additional costs to enable Data Cloud on sandbox. When this feature was in beta, no additional SKUs were needed, so everyone is confused right now

we have also asked Nate and Aaron if we can just match the SKUs we use in a trial org but they weren't able to copy or detect SKU used in a trial org and suggested to check in digital wallet, but it is not available in a trial org

It sounds like you're a partner in which case you can just ping me directly on Slack or in the Partner Community.
